# Simple SVN -- How do I lock content for Edit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I am in the process of editing content that I want to later check into SVN (Tortoise SVN, to be precise) and I want to lock the content on the SVN server because I am making a minor edit and update, how do I do this?

At a previous job, we would just verbally tell everyone on the team that an update was in progress.  But now, everyone is not in the same room.  Is there some way to lock a project while you update the content?

I did not immediately see a menu option for this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30OlZ2E3F2o

Answer (score 1):

RClick on file - `TortoiseSVN` - `Get lock...`

[image: Lock in TSVN]

You must also [RTFM](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) at least TortoiseSVN Guide, while [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html) will be better choice